# With XSLT, how can I process normally, but hold some nodes until the end and then output them all at once (e.g. footnotes)?

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT application which reads the internal format of Microsoft Word 2007/2010 zipped XML and translates it into HTML5 with XSLT. I am investigating how to add the ability to optionally read OpenOffice documents instead of MSWord.

Microsoft stores XML for footnote text separately from the XML of the document text, which happens to suit me because I want the footnotes in a block at the end of the output HTML page.

However, unfortunately for me, OpenOffice puts each footnote right next to its reference, inline with the text of the document.  Here is a simple paragraph example:

```
  <text:p text:style-name="Standard">The real breakthrough in aerial mapping 
    during World War II was trimetrogon
    <text:note text:id="ftn0" text:note-class="footnote">
      <text:note-citation>1</text:note-citation>
      <text:note-body>
        <text:p text:style-name="Footnote">Three separate cameras took three
          photographs at once, a direct downward and an oblique on each side.</text:p>
      </text:note-body>
    </text:note>
    photography, but the camera was large and heavy, so there were problems finding
    the right aircraft to carry it.
  </text:p>
```

My question is, can XSLT process the XML as normal, but hold each of the text:note items until the end of the document text, and then emit them all at one time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as "holding" the `text:note` items, instead simply ignore them in the main pass and then gather them at the end with a `//text:note` and process them there, e.g.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:text="whateveritshouldbe">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- normal mode - replace text:note element by [reference] -->
  <xsl:template match="text:note">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('[', text:note-citation, ']')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <document>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
      <footnotes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//text:note" mode="footnotes"/>
      </footnotes>
    </document>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- special "footnotes" mode to de-activate the usual text:node template -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="footnotes">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="footnotes" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking of your logic as being driven by the order of things in the input, but in XSLT you need to be driven by the order of things in the output. When you get to the point where you want to output the footnotes, go find the footnote text wherever it might be in the input. Admittedly that doesn't always play too well with the apply-templates recursive descent processing model, which is explicitly input-driven; but nevertheless, that's the way you have to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use <xsl:apply-templates mode="..."/>. I'm not sure on the exact syntax and your use case, but maybe the example below will give you a clue on how to approach your problem.

Basic idea is to process your nodes twice. First iteration would be pretty much the same as now, and the second iteration only looks for footnotes and only outputs those. You differentiate those iteration by setting "mode" parameter.

Maybe this example will give you a clue how to approach your problem. Note that I used different tags that in your code, so the example would be simpler.

XSLT sheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="doc">
    <xml>
      <!-- First iteration - skip footnotes -->
      <doc>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text" />
      </doc>

      <!-- Second iteration, extract all footnotes.
           'mode' = footnotes -->
      <footnotes>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text" mode="footnotes" />
      </footnotes>
    </xml>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Note: no mode attribute -->
  <xsl:template match="text">
    <text>
      <xsl:for-each select="p">
        <p>
          <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
        </p>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </text>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Note: mode = footnotes -->
  <xsl:template match="text" mode="footnotes">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//footnote">
      <footnote>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
      </footnote>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
  <text>
    <p>
      some text
      <footnote>footnote1</footnote>
    </p>
    <p>
      other text
      <footnote>footnote2</footnote>
    </p>
  </text>
  <text>
    <p>
      some text2
      <footnote>footnote3</footnote>
    </p>
    <p>
      other text2
      <footnote>footnote4</footnote>
    </p>
  </text>
</doc>
```

Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml>
  <!-- Output from first iteration -->
  <doc>
    <text>
      <p>some text</p>
      <p>other text</p>
    </text>
    <text>
      <p>some text2</p>
      <p>other text2</p>
    </text>
  </doc>

  <!-- Output from second iteration -->
  <footnotes>
    <footnote>footnote1</footnote>
    <footnote>footnote2</footnote>
    <footnote>footnote3</footnote>
    <footnote>footnote4</footnote>
  </footnotes>
</xml>
```