# Footnote replacement to the end of the chapter

Tags: html, xslt

In the input xml, I have no of footnotes inside each paragraph in each section. I want to set a link where the footnote is available and i need to move all footnote to the end of the chapter in html.

For your reference i am pasting piece of my input.

```
<section level="1">
<heading class="hdgautonum1" level="1"><inline style="\-ilx-tab-stops: left blank 0tw; "><gentext type="headingnumberstring">1  </gentext>Introduction</inline></heading>
<par class="para"><inline class="glossaryrefmain">ITIL</inline> is part of a suite of best-practice publications for <inline class="glossaryrefmain">IT service management</inline> (ITSM).<inline class="footnote&#160;reference"><footnote>
<par class="footnote&#160;text"> ITSM and other concepts from this chapter are described in more detail in Chapter 2.</par></footnote></inline> ITIL provides guidance to <inline class="glossaryrefmain">service provider</inline>s on the provision of quality</par>
</section>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far - then, it is easier to tell you where you went wrong. What version of XSLT are you using?

Comment: This is basically the same problem as building an index, except that (a) you're inserting the footnote tag at the point being "indexed" and (b) the second pass for the "index" occurs after the body of the text rather than before. Take a look at the indexing examples on the [XSL FAQ](http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html) website, which collects past solutions to common problems; I haven't found a footnote answer there yet but there are index examples which could be adapted.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269554/with-xslt-how-can-i-process-normally-but-hold-some-nodes-until-the-end-and-the?rq=1

Comment: @Muller, I haven't tried that i am pondering on that. I am looking for help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <!-- copies all nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- generate footnote link -->
    <xsl:template match="footnote">
        <xref>
            <xsl:attribute name="rid">fn<xsl:number level="any" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:number level="any" format="1"/>
        </xref>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- removes container footnote&#160;reference, or you can retain them, just remove the comment marks o xsl:copy -->
    <xsl:template match="inline[contains(@class, 'footnote')]">
        <!--<xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>-->
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <!--</xsl:copy>-->
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- moves all footnotes at the end -->
    <xsl:template match="section">
        <root>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:copy>
            <footnote-group>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//footnote" mode="group"/>
            </footnote-group>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- template to fix footnotes, in a different mode -->
    <xsl:template match="footnote" mode="group">
        <footnote>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">fn<xsl:number level="any" format="1"/></xsl:attribute>
            <label><xsl:number level="any" format="1"/></label>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </footnote>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to your input XML, it outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <section level="1">
        <heading class="hdgautonum1" level="1">
            <inline style="\-ilx-tab-stops: left blank 0tw; "><gentext type="headingnumberstring">1
                </gentext>Introduction</inline>
        </heading>
        <par class="para"><inline class="glossaryrefmain">ITIL</inline> is part of a suite of
            best-practice publications for <inline class="glossaryrefmain">IT service
                management</inline> (ITSM).<xref rid="fn1">1</xref> ITIL provides guidance to
                <inline class="glossaryrefmain">service provider</inline>s on the provision of
            quality</par>
    </section>
    <footnote-group>
        <footnote id="fn1">
            <label>1</label>
            <par class="footnote text"> ITSM and other concepts from this chapter are described in
                more detail in Chapter 2.</par>
        </footnote>
    </footnote-group>
</root>
```